# LTC2498 Temperature Sensor Chip Code via SPI

Tags: microcontroller, programming, programmer, power-electronics

I would be very grateful for your tips for my present problem definition:

I have a microcontroller ATmega128RFA1 with integrated Zigbee with UART-USB(TTL Converter) attached to the PC.

From the ATmega128RFA1 I have connected via SPI a LTC2498 Temperature Sensor Chip.

I need to read The Temperature from LTC2498 on The Terminal Program in my PC.
The scheme is as follows:

LTC2498--SPI--uC(Programmed with code Read_ltc2498)--UART_USB--PC.

The code with which I am working is as follows:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


#define DD_MISO 3
#define DD_MOSI 2
#define DD_SCK 1
#define DD_SS 0




void uart_init()
{
    uint16_t temp = ((8000000)/(9600.0*16)-1); //Berechnung Übertragungsgeschwindigkeit


    UBRR0L = temp; //Übertragungsgeschwindigkeit übermitteln
    UBRR0H = temp>>8;

    UCSR0B |= (1<<TXEN0)|(1<<RXEN0)|(1<<RXCIE0); //Senden und Empfangen freischalten


    UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ00)|(1<<UCSZ01);  //Übertragungsformat: 8-Bit

}


int sendestring(char *s)
{
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        while bit_is_clear(UCSR0A, UDRE0); //warten, bis UDRE0 = 1 (Senderegister frei)

        UDR0 = s[i]; //ein Zeichen senden

    }

    return 0;
}




void SPI_MasterInit(void)
{
    //Outputs: MOSI, SCK, SS
    DDRB = (1<<DD_MOSI)|(1<<DD_SCK)|(1<<DD_SS);

    //Enable SPI, Master-Mode, set clock rate fck/16
    SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR0);
}


int SPI_MasterTransmit(char MOSI)
{
    //start Transmission
    SPDR = MOSI;

    //wait for transmission complete
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));

    //returned data from slave to master
    return SPDR;
}


int main()
{

    char str[20];

    // Thermoelement an CH0 und CH1
    char masterOut1 = 0b10100000;

    // interne Temperaturmessung:
    char masterOut2 = 0b10000000;

    char result;
    uint32_t masterIn = 0;
    uint32_t Temp = 0;

    uart_init();    

    SPI_MasterInit();


    for(;;)
    {

        _delay_ms(500);

        //CS des Thermochips auf low
        PORTB &= !(1<<DD_SS);


        //Byte1
        result = SPI_MasterTransmit(masterOut1);        
        masterIn = (result & 0b00011111);  /*last 3 bits lost/*
        sendestring(str);

        //Byte2
        result = SPI_MasterTransmit(masterOut2);
        masterIn = (masterIn<<8) + result;


        //Byte3
        result = SPI_MasterTransmit(0);
        masterIn = (masterIn<<8) + result;


        //Byte4
        result = SPI_MasterTransmit(0);
        masterIn = (masterIn<<8) + result;


        //CS des Thermochips auf high
        PORTB |= (1<<DD_SS);


        masterIn = (masterIn>>5) & 0b00000000111111111111111111111111; /*Last 5 bits lost/*

        sendestring(" masterIn: ");
        sprintf(str, "%ld", masterIn);
        sendestring(str);

        //bei interner Temperaturmessung: Temperatur in °C berechnen laut Datenblatt Seite21
        Temp = (masterIn*4/1570)-273;

        sendestring(" Temp: ");
        sprintf(str, "%ld", Temp);
        sendestring(str);

        _delay_ms(2000);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I have tried change in SPI function the 4 modes for CPOL and CPHA bits in the SPCR Register but doesn´t work.

With the next chars I have LTC2498 configured as follows:

32 bits:
Byte1= 10100000;
Byte2= 10000000;
Byte3= 00000000;
Byte4= 00000000;

The results are around this:
result1: 11111111 masterIn: 16777215 Temp: 42471

masterIn = DATAOUT according to the LTC2498 DataSheet has to be around 80000, so is too high.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody Know about SPI connection? I need help, please.

Comment: Help Please!!! I have tried all but is impossible!

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if this will solve your problem but I would suggest you to do this change:

```
//CS des Thermochips auf low
PORTB &= ~(1<<DD_SS);
```

Have you tried measuring with an oscilloscope?

Edit: Also noticed now that your comment syntax is a bit off, maybe problem when you pasted it to the forum? Does the code compile?

```
 masterIn = (result & 0b00011111);  /*last 3 bits lost/*
```

Should be:

```
masterIn = (result & 0b00011111);  /*last 3 bits lost*/
```

And:

```
masterIn = (masterIn>>5) & 0b00000000111111111111111111111111; /*Last 5 bits lost/*
```

Should be:

```
masterIn = (masterIn>>5) & 0b00000000111111111111111111111111; /*Last 5 bits lost*/
```